# Remove rows containing all 0s but keep those with NA in r

Tags: r, na

I have a dataframe where there are numeric columns containing NA values with one character column that is populated, e.g.

| Shoes | q1_sales | q2_sales | q3_sales | q4_sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Winter Collection | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| Boots | 50 | 25 | 0 | 100 |
| Trainers | 40 | 65 | 200 | 100 |
| Loafers | 0 | 45 | 20 | 10 |
| Summer Collection | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| Trainers | 50 | 655 | 400 | 0 |
| Flip Flops | 0 | 25 | 40 | 0 |
| Sandals | 0 | 205 | 45 | 25 |
| Other | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| Clogs | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

I want to try and remove the numeric columns that sum to 0 (e.g. clogs), but keep the NA columns with the first character column remaining in place.

I tried using the following code to remove the 0 rows:

df[apply(df[,-1], 1, function(x) !all(x==0)),]

However, it resulted in the data frame removing the character values for the first column, e.g.:

| Shoes | q1_sales | q2_sales | q3_sales | q4_sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NA | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| Boots | 50 | 25 | 0 | 100 |
| Trainers | 40 | 65 | 200 | 100 |
| Loafers | 0 | 45 | 20 | 10 |
| NA | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| Trainers | 50 | 655 | 400 | 0 |
| Flip Flops | 0 | 25 | 40 | 0 |
| Sandals | 0 | 205 | 45 | 25 |
| NA | NA | NA | NA | NA |

Here is what I want to see (the original table with the 'clogs' row removed, but the character column intact):

| Shoes | q1_sales | q2_sales | q3_sales | q4_sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Winter Collection | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| Boots | 50 | 25 | 0 | 100 |
| Trainers | 40 | 65 | 200 | 100 |
| Loafers | 0 | 45 | 20 | 10 |
| Summer Collection | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| Trainers | 50 | 655 | 400 | 0 |
| Flip Flops | 0 | 25 | 40 | 0 |
| Sandals | 0 | 205 | 45 | 25 |
| Other | NA | NA | NA | NA |

Comment: How about a row with `0, 0, NA, NA`? Keep or drop?

Answer (score 1):

```
tmp=rowSums(df[,-1])
df[is.na(tmp) | tmp!=0,]

              Shoes q1_sales q2_sales q3_sales q4_sales
1 Winter Collection       NA       NA       NA       NA
2             Boots       50       25        0      100
3          Trainers       40       65      200      100
4           Loafers        0       45       20       10
5 Summer Collection       NA       NA       NA       NA
6          Trainers       50      655      400        0
7        Flip Flops        0       25       40        0
8           Sandals        0      205       45       25
9             Other       NA       NA       NA       NA
```

Answer (score 1):

*EDIT*: (following @DarrenTsai's valubale comment)

A `tidyverse` solution:

```
df %>%
  filter(!if_all(matches("^q"), ~ . == 0) | if_any(matches("^q"), is.na))
```

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr`, you can use `if_all` and `if_any` inside `filter()`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(!if_all(-Shoes, ~ .x == 0) | if_any(-Shoes, is.na))

#               Shoes q1_sales q2_sales q3_sales q4_sales
# 1 Winter_Collection       NA       NA       NA       NA
# 2             Boots       50       25        0      100
# 3          Trainers       40       65      200      100
# 4           Loafers        0       45       20       10
# 5 Summer_Collection       NA       NA       NA       NA
# 6          Trainers       50      655      400        0
# 7        Flip_Flops        0       25       40        0
# 8           Sandals        0      205       45       25
# 9             Other       NA       NA       NA       NA
```

---

###### Data

```r
df <- structure(list(Shoes = c("Winter_Collection", "Boots", "Trainers", 
"Loafers", "Summer_Collection", "Trainers", "Flip_Flops", "Sandals", 
"Other", "Clogs"), q1_sales = c(NA, 50L, 40L, 0L, NA, 50L, 0L, 
0L, NA, 0L), q2_sales = c(NA, 25L, 65L, 45L, NA, 655L, 25L, 205L, NA, 0L),
q3_sales = c(NA, 0L, 200L, 20L, NA, 400L, 40L, 45L, NA, 0L),
q4_sales = c(NA, 100L, 100L, 10L, NA, 0L, 0L, 25L, NA, 0L)),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```